# MVC4 DropDownListFor how to return selected value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to use a dropdown in an MVC4 view and came accross [Html.DropdownList different Behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26959234/html-dropdownlist-different-behaviour) which led me to try using @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedProdType, (IEnumerable)ViewBag.ProdTypes, "Select Product Type", new { @class="form-control"}) in my view - which worked after I changed the SelectedProdType to IEnumerable in the Model - (wouldn't work if SelectedProdType was either a String or an Integer). The various Product Types are correctly listed and can be selected in the View and everything seems to work without any errors - except the ProdTypeID which I need to be returned when a selection is made defaults to 0 instead of the ID of the selected Product Type. I tried assigning the SelectedProdType to the ProdTypeID (after converting it to Int) in the Controller - but this obviously didn't work. HOW do I get the ID no. of the selected Product Type to get returned to be included amongst the various other Product fields that are saved to the DB when this CREATE form is submitted, please? I'm using a Stored Procedure with a DB (and I'm NOT using the Entity Framework, although that shouldn't matter - so, examples with just text lists - which seems to be all that I can find - don't help me).

Limited extracted bits from my code (hope this is sufficient)?

In the Model:

```
[Display(Name = "Select Product Type")]
public int ProdTypeID { get; set; }

public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SelectedProdType { get; set; }
```

and

```
public DataSet GetProductsByTypes()
    {
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DHQWDBST101;User ID=wswebuser;Password=WSDBReader10!;Initial Catalog=WSTechnology");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_GetProductsByTypes", cn);
        cn.Open();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        DataSet dst = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dst);
        cn.Close();
        return dst;            
    }
```

and

```
public int CreateProduct(int _OrganisationID, int _ProdTypeID, string _ProductName, string _ProductDescription, string _ProductComments, string _ProductProfileLocation, string _ProductProfileName, string _ProductMIMEType, string _ProductSerialNumber, int _CreatedBy, bool _MarkedDelete, int _NewProductID)  
    {
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DHQWDBST101;User ID=wswebuser;Password=WSDBReader10!;Initial Catalog=WSTechnology");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_AddProduct", cn);
        cn.Open();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductTypeID", 1);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrganisationID", _OrganisationID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProdTypeID", _ProdTypeID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductName", _ProductName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductDescription", _ProductDescription);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductComments", _ProductComments);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductProfileLocation", _ProductProfileLocation);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductMIMEType", _ProductMIMEType);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductProfileName", _ProductProfileName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductSerialNumber", _ProductSerialNumber);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreatedBy", _CreatedBy);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MarkedDelete", _MarkedDelete);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewProductID", 0);

        return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); ;
    }
```

In the Controller GET:

```
 // GET: /Products/Create
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Create(CreateProductModel createproductmodel)
    {
        DataSet dst = createproductmodel.GetProductsByTypes();
        ViewBag.ProdTypes = dst.Tables[0];

        List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();

        foreach (System.Data.DataRow dr in ViewBag.ProdTypes.Rows)
        {
            items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = @dr["Descr"].ToString(), Value = @dr["ProdTypeID"].ToString() });

        }

        ViewBag.ProdTypes = items;

        return View();
```

and the POST in the Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    [Authorize]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(OrganisationNames organisationnames, CreateProductModel createproductmodel, FormCollection selection, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
```

skipped a lot of (hopefully) unimportant code and

```
createproductmodel.ProdTypeID = Convert.ToInt32(createproductmodel.SelectedProdType);

                    int _records = createproductmodel.CreateProduct(createproductmodel.OrganisationID, createproductmodel.ProdTypeID, createproductmodel.ProductName, createproductmodel.ProductDescription, createproductmodel.ProductComments, ViewBag.FileURL, ViewBag.MIMEType, ViewBag.FileName, createproductmodel.ProductSerialNumber, createproductmodel.CreatedBy, createproductmodel.MarkedDelete, createproductmodel.NewProductID);

                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Products");
```

In the View:

```
    <div class="editor-label">      
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProdTypeID)             
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedProdType, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.ProdTypes, "Select Product Type", new { @class="form-control"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProdTypeID)
    </div>
```

Strangely, DropDownListFor isn't covered in the 2 MVC4 books I have and I haven't been able to Google anything remotely near what I'm trying to do and nothing useful turned up in a search of StackOverflow, so, I'm hoping some expert has a simple solution for this clueless newbie? (And everyone else trying to use DropDownListFor in MVC for the first time).

We'll really appreciate your explanation of what exactly to do to get the selected ID returned, please.

Comment: Your code makes no sense.  You're redirecting to an action... that resets everything.  You're not actually doing anything with _records....

Comment: SelectedProductType should be whatever type your Value type is in your collection of SelectListItem's

Comment: Thank you for the instant response - I was still adding some extra code that hopefully will now make things a bit clearer?

Well the database does get updated with everything created EXCEPT the ProductTypeID (which is just 0).

I just intended to redirect to the Products listing view after the CREATE view is submitted - which works - the newly created product is listed - obviously, just not it's type.

Comment: I had it originally set to the type of my Value type of SelectListItem (Integer) but an error was generated stating that it HAD to be of type IEnumerable<SelectListItem> - which forced me to use that? 

Can I just get a working example of DropDownListFor that returns an Integer when selected, please?

I really appreciate your help, Erik.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding error messages.  You are jumping to conclusions.  Rather than doing the correct thing, and asking about the error message you get, you are making bad assumptions, changing your code to do the wrong thing, then trying to ask how to make the wrong thing work.  This is a good tutorial http://nimblegecko.com/using-simple-drop-down-lists-in-ASP-NET-MVC/

Comment: OK - I accept that. I'll try returning to my original condition and will submit a request for how to get around that error message instead then. Thanks for your help, Erik.

Comment: I added an example of what you asked for, it's a string and not an integer.  The problem is that your code is assigning a string value not an integer to the SelectListItem

Comment: Well that's embarassing - NOW what was generating an error earlier suddenly just works!!! AND the reCaptcha that previously wasn't working has suddenly also started working! I assume the problem must have been something in my system that has somehow strangely righted itself!! Really weird, but I'm VERY grateful I can carry on now!
Really appreciate your patience, Erik! My apologies for wasting your time! Can you maybe just delete this entire Question that will help nobody?

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial link too, Erik! I really appreciate your patient help.

Comment: Had a glance at the linked tutorial and it's exactly what I was looking for but somehow couldn't seem to find - REALLY appreciated, Erik!